# Magento 2 developer mode exception issue

Tags: magento2

I have recently moved Magento 2 installation from local host to server and after solving file permission issues I am stuck at the following exception.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Path
> "/home/onelifehair/public_html/pub/static/" cannot be used with
> directory "/home/onelifehair/public_html/pub/static/"

I have tried to solve this by fixing windows path issue as mentioned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251924/invalid-template-file-magento2-3-0), but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

just do this in your terminal

```
chmod -R 777 /home/onelifehair/public_html/pub/static/
```